# Uploading JSON file in unsorted order to R

Tags: json, r

I have a large JSON file in this format.

```
{ "author" : "abc" , "arch" :true , "created_date" : 1425820274  }
{ "created_date" : 1199231993 , "author" : "xyz" , "arch" : false }
```

Basically its not in a sorted order and I want to create a dataframe.

I tried the following code.

```
path <- "C:/Users/***/Downloads/RC"
c <- file(path, "r")
l <- readLines(c, -1L)
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(l,fromJSON)))
```

but its not merging it in a sorted order. How do I sort a list before merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `fromJSON` function from the  `jsonlite` package, it does not care what order it finds properties within each object.

```
js <- '[
{ "author" : "abc" , "arch" :true , "created_date" : 1425820274  },
{ "created_date" : 1199231993 , "author" : "xyz" , "arch" : false }
]'

library(jsonlite)

fromJSON(js)
```

Prints this data frame:

```
  author  arch created_date
1    abc  TRUE   1425820274
2    xyz FALSE   1199231993
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found that for the type of data that I have stream_in() from library(jsonlite) is perfect. I don't have to modify the file.